# SharePoint 2010 - Unable to delete list item

Tags: delete

I have to delete list item but not able to do due to some permission issue : 
1. Ribbon
2. Powershell
3. Information Policy Management 
4. Logging through site collection admin / App pool account

Unable to see the permission for item through "Manage Item Permission".

Any other way to delete item.

Comment: Try to navigate to the list, change to Datasheet view under 'List' tab in ribbon and delete the item.

Comment: deleting / editing through datasheet is not working for the item.

Comment: Download the Sharepoint Manager and try to delete  using SPM.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure that the item isn't a declared record?  If it is, you'll be unable to delete it via any means.

If you use List Settings --> Record Declaration Settings and check there; make sure the option "Always allow the manual declaration of records" is checked.

Back in your main list, via the Title Drop Down; look for Compliance Details Options and undeclare the item as a record if it is indeed a record.  You should then be able to delete it.

Comment: Item is not a declared record.Compliance policy says : Not a record
You cannot declare/undeclare item as a record.

Answer (score 1):

Does it show any errors while you try to delete the item? Please check the event logs and SharePoint logs for any errors and let us know. Also, if possible try out on a different PC/Browser.

Alternatively, if it is in test environment save the list as template with data, create a new list using the template and try to delete the item in the new list to see if it works.